# Avoiding a call to CommandBarControl.Picture

Tags: c#, vba, error-handling, rubberduck

Earlier today, I encountered an Access Violation error when opening the VBE for SolidWorks 2006, while Rubberduck VBA was initializing.

I traced the Access Violation back to an attempt to set the Picture property of a CommandBarButton, and then [posted on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39061559/how-can-i-pre-emptively-determine-if-accessing-a-property-will-cause-an-accessvi)

Initially, I suspected that SolidWorks might have implemented the VBE in some wacky out-of-process way, as the Picture property uses StdOle's `IPictureDisp` which will throw an AccessViolation on crossing a process boundary.

But upon skipping the Picture assignments, Rubberduck was able to fully load, and I discovered that SolidWorks 2006's VBE has `CommandBarControl`'s that don't have `Picture` or `Mask` properties.

A little more digging, and it became clear that Office first introduced `Picture` and `Mask` in Office XP, but evidently SolidWorks hadn't updated the CommandBars within their VBE implementation (they possibly used an older version of the VBA SDK?).

Rubberduck is using the embedded types of the Office Interop Assembly that contains the CommandBar types, and that is from *after* Office XP.

So it seems that accessing the non-existent `Picture` and `Mask` properties would *ordinarily* cause a catchable exception, but because they involve StdOle, .NET sees a process boundary has been crossed and throws an AccessViolation.

I had to find a way of safely setting the picture, so I've elected to cast the button to a `dynamic` and then try reading the property. I *could* have just cast to `dynamic` and set the `Picture`, but it seemed to deserve its own helper function, `HasPictureProperty`...

```
    public static void SetButtonImage(CommandBarButton button, Image image, Image mask)
    {
        button.FaceId = 0;
        if (image == null || mask == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (!HasPictureProperty(button))
        {
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            button.Picture = AxHostConverter.ImageToPictureDisp(image);
            button.Mask = AxHostConverter.ImageToPictureDisp(mask);
        }
        catch (COMException exception)
        {
            Logger.Debug("Button image could not be set for button [" + button.Caption + "]\n" + exception);
        }
    }

    private static bool HasPictureProperty(CommandBarButton button)
    {
        try
        {
            dynamic control = button;
            object picture = control.Picture;
            return true;
        }

        catch (Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException exception)
        {
            Logger.Debug("Button image cannot be set for button [" + button.Caption + "], because Host VBE CommandBars are too old.\n" + exception);
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Am I abusing `dynamic` in this instance? Should I have perhaps have opted for reflection over catching what might be many `RuntimeBinderException`'s?

BTW - The upside of this fix will mean that Rubberduck VBA *should* now support Office 2000 and earlier, albeit the Rubberduck toolbar buttons won't have images.

Answer (score 1):

`SetButtonImage` is called for every single `CommandMenuItem` in Rubberduck, regardless of whether or not `Picture` and `Mask` are overridden.

Whether a `CommandBarButton` has a `Picture` property depends on the [version of the] host application, and the `bool` result of `HasPictureProperty` will be the same for every single `CommandMenuItem` being initialized: if a `RuntimeBinderException` is thrown with the first button, it will be thrown and logged *for every single button* - this is a massive performance hit: throwing and catching exceptions like this, is pretty expensive.

I'm ok with the `dynamic` cast - though some reflection might actually perform better, but without changing the logic to stop making that test for every single button it would still be inefficient.

The first `HasPictureProperty` return value will be the value returned by every single subsequent call: you need to change the logic so as to avoid making that check more than once.